# Salesforce SOQL How can i target an id that is in another table

Tags: salesforce, soql

i am trying to figure out **how to do a specific query** but i am limited by my knowledge. So any help would be deeply appreciated.

I have some objects: **Employee, Employee role assignment, Student group etc..**

What i am trying to do is:

Inside every Employee personal page, create a table, that has student info of students that have picked the student group that is assigned to the specific employee. The relationship between objects are Employee to employee role assignment(one to many), employee role assignment to Student group(many to one). Each Employee is assigned many roles and each role is assigned a student group.

What i am trying to do is something like this:

```
SELECT Opportunity__r.Name, Opportunity__r.Email__c, Opportunity__r.Phone__c, Opportunity__r.Parent_Guardian_Email__c, Student_group__r.Name, Opportunity__r.Personal_Statement__c FROM Content__c WHERE Student_group_r.Employee_role_assignment__r.Employee__r.Id = :id
```

The last part, after the WHERE, is what i am stuck at. Is there a way to pass the id?

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce terminology, Employee Role Assignment is a *junction object*.

You're adding in a couple of extra objects here that make this more challenging. It looks like you have a lookup relationship from `Content__c` to `Opportunity` and also from `Content__c` to `Student_Group__c`, and most of the data that you want is actually located on the Opportunity. `Content__c` is something like a second junction object here.

You want to filter your Opportunities based on whether they are associated with a Content that is associated with a Student Group that is associated with the Employee whose page this is. Whew.

If I understood your data model correctly, you can achieve this using a semi-join sub-select.
It would look something like this:

```
List<Content__c> results = [
    SELECT Opportunity__r.Name, Opportunity__r.Email__c, Opportunity__r.Phone__c ...
    FROM Content__c
    WHERE Student_Group__c IN (
        SELECT Student_Group__c 
        FROM Employee_Role_Assignment__c 
        WHERE Employee__c = :thisEmployeeId
    )
];
```

The Apex binding with `:` in the inner `WHERE` clause is what injects the Id of the Employee, stored in some local variable, into the query.